# EXISTS command vs IN command

Tags: sql

For reference, I am trying to answer a SQL question at: https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-subqueries-exercise-21.php

And the answer is:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, department_id 
FROM employees 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM employees 
              WHERE salary > 3700);
```

But can someone please explain why the above does not return the same result as:

```
SELECT e1.first_name, e1.last_name, e1.department_id 
FROM employees AS e1
WHERE e1.employee_id IN (SELECT e2.employee_id 
                         FROM employees AS e2
                         WHERE e2.salary > 3700);
```

Answer (score 1):

The EXISTS clause gives a value of TRUE or FALSE.  The statement that you've written will give a value of TRUE if there is any row at all in `employees` with a salary of more than 3700.  You did not include any condition that requires that row to match the id of the employee you're checking.

If you want to add such a condition, you'd write (assuming a unique employee id exists and is called `employee_id`):

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, department_id 
FROM employees E1
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT * 
FROM employees 
WHERE salary > 3700 AND employee_id = E1.employee_id )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I get confused as to what it means when it says it "returns TRUE or FALSE". Is that "returning" to each individual outer query call?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  For each row in your main query, you are asking "Is it true that a row with the following criteria exists"?  If the answer to that question is yes, then the outer query row will be included in the results.  Because you did not *correlate* the EXISTS query with the outer query, it's *always* true.

Comment: Awesome! That answers my question!

Answer (score 0):

The first has no correlation clause.  Hence, it either returns all rows in `employees` (if any row matching the condition exists).  Or it returns no rows in `employees` (if no such rows exist).

The second is comparing the rows in the subquery to the id in the outer query.  The equivalent query using `exists` would be:

```
SELECT e1.first_name, e1.last_name, e1.department_id 
FROM employees AS e1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT e2.employee_id 
              FROM employees AS e2
              WHERE e2.employee_id = e1.employee_id AND
                    e2.salary > 3700
              );
```

Of course, one would expect the `employee_id` to be the primary key for a table called `employee`s.  So this would do the same thing:

```
SELECT e1.first_name, e1.last_name, e1.department_id 
FROM employees AS e1
WHERE e1.salary > 3700
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just ran your suggested query and it is returning the same result set that my query returned (which is still different from the first query's result set). For some reason, it looks like that first query is returning 40 more rows than both our queries.

Comment: Ok nevermind, I see what you are saying about that query... So basically what I was doing with my "IN" query is giving the same result as your new query and that is what I would expect because you added in that new condition!